# GtkAboutDialog icon not loading?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm attempting to add an about dialog to my next bit of tutorial code, but I can't get the icon to load for some reason. Below is the entire function for creating and displaying the dialog.

```
static void help_clicked(GtkButton *button, GtkWindow *window)
{
    const gchar *authors[] = { "me", NULL };
    const gchar *license = "somestuff";
    GdkPixbuf *logo = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("logo.png", NULL);

    gtk_show_about_dialog(window,
                            "authors", authors, "license", license, "license-type", GTK_LICENSE_CUSTOM,
                            "logo", logo, "logo-icon-name", "Logo Icon",
                            "program-name", "Chapter 6, Exercise 1",
                            "version", "1.0",
                            "comments", "This is just an exercise from Chapter 6 of the book I'm reading.",
                            "website", "http://www.google.com", "website-label", "Application Homepage",
                            "copyright", "(C) 2014 Patrick Meyer",
                            "wrap-license", TRUE, NULL);
}
```

This results in an about dialog with every attribute successfully set except the icon.

The weird thing is, the exact same call to `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file()` works in `main()` when I supply it to `gtk_window_set_icon()`. This is a single-file program with `logo.png` present in the directory of execution. What's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as the API reference clearly states, the `GtkAboutDialog:logo-icon-name` property overrides the `GtkAboutDialog:logo` property:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAboutDialog.html#GtkAboutDialog--logo-icon-name

also, you're passing a value for the `logo-icon-name` property that does not mean anything; the `logo-icon-name` property requires a *named icon* according to the [Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html).

just remove the `logo-icon-name` property and you'll see the correct icon.

as a side note from your example: you should release the reference on the `GdkPixbuf` object you create after `gtk_show_about_dialog()` returns, otherwise you will leak it. ideally, though, since you don't want to load the image file from disk every time you click the help button, you should use something like this:

```
static GdkPixbuf *logo_icon = NULL;

if (logo_icon == NULL)
  logo_icon = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("logo.png", NULL);

gtk_show_about_dialog (...);
```

which will keep the pixbuf around for the duration of your application.

another option is to use `GResource` and inject the image data into the application's binary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `logo-icon-name` property. As it is stated [inside the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAboutDialog.html#GtkAboutDialog--logo-icon-name), this overwrites the `logo` property. If you leave out the `logo-icon-name` property, the logo will show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting `logo-icon-name` too which is supposed to be a symbolic name for an icon, not a human description.

So the internal image is being set correctly and then replaced internally a second time. This also explains why calling `gtk_window_set_icon()` afterwards works correctly.